# Liquibase Update Failed

Tags: liquibase

I am using the following the quickstart on [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/quickstart)

My xml Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<databaseChangeLog
  xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd">

    <changeSet id="1" author="bob">
        <createTable tableName="department">
            <column name="id" type="int">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="varchar(50)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="active" type="boolean" defaultValueBoolean="true"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

When I run Liquibase via command line using "update" command .Liquibase tells me this

```
INFO 8/31/12 9:17 AM:liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
Liquibase Update Failed: Content is not allowed in prolog.
SEVERE 8/31/12 9:17 AM:liquibase: Content is not allowed in prolog.
liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: Error parsing line 1 column 1 of dat
abase.xml: Content is not allowed in prolog.
        at liquibase.parser.core.xml.XMLChangeLogSAXParser.parse(XMLChangeLogSAXP
arser.java:106)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:107)
```

My update command is

```
liquibase --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver  --classpath=mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar   --changeLogFile=database.xml --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample" --username=root --password=password  update
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because there are several hidden characters (such as BOM, google XML BOM for more information) at the beginning of your XML file.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295472/how-do-i-remove-the-bom-character-from-my-xml-file) shows how to remove BOM.

If you are using Windows, [XVI32](http://www.chmaas.handshake.de/delphi/freeware/xvi32/xvi32.htm) (a free hex editor) would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Liquibase JIRA issue](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2722)

This problem is related to schema definitions...try with schema definition from attachment example of the given link