# Python: Can dumpdata cannot loaddata back. UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, django, json, postgresql

I have been using Python 2.7, Django 1.5 and PostgreSQL 9.2 for two weeks. Never saw it before. Everything is freshly installed on my Windows 7 machine, so it should have default settings. Django beautifully generates tables in my db. Looks like everything works fine.
I am able to  dump data from my database by running:

```
manage.py dumpdata > test.json
```

or

```
manage.py dumpdata  --indent4 > test.json
```

I saw that the JSON file it looks  as it should.

Then, I truncate some tables and try to load them from the JSON file with:

```
python manage.py loaddata database = T2  test.json    // or without db name
```

I got the following error:

> “UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position
>   0: invalid start byte”

If I open the test.json file in notepad, save it as `utf8` and try again, then I get:

> “No JSON object could be decoded”

The file still looks OK, not empty.

By the way, when I open the JSON file with notepad it offers me to save it as Unicode. My database has UTF8 encoding. Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: Do not use Notepad to modify the code

Comment: show `print(repr(open('test.json', 'rb').read(4)))`

Answer (score 35):

What worked for me is following these steps:

```
- Open the file in regular notepad
- Select save as
- Select encoding "UTF-8" (Not "UTF-8 (With BOM)")
- Save the file.
```

Now you can use loaddata.

However, this only works for files that are small enough for notepad to open.

Comment: achieved in notepad++ by setting utf-8 via Encoding -> UTF-8, then saving

Comment: Works in VSCode too

Answer (score 7):

`0xff` in position 0 looks like the start of a little-endian UTF-16 [byte order marker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to me.  Notepad's "Unicode" save mode is little-endian UTF-16, so that makes sense if you saved your json from Notepad after creating it.  Notepad will keep the byte order marker even in utf-8, which could plausibly cause loaddata to fail to parse it.

If you don't have your un-edited json still handy, you'll need to remove the BOM - personally I'd use emacs, but [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295472/how-do-i-remove-the-bom-character-from-my-xml-file) suggested this stand-alone Windows .exe:

http://www.bryntyounce.com/filebomdetector.htm

Comment: Peter,Thank you for your reply. I cannot use emacs since I have Windows7. I did install utility you suggested and run it. Indeed it shows that all files but one doctored by Notepad are  UTF-16. However after running the utility I still have the same “UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte”

Comment: Step 1: convert to UTF-8.  Step 2: Remove the BOM.

Comment: "I cannot use emacs since I have Windows7": Yes, you can. https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/download.html

Answer (score 4):

On windows, if you run your standard dumpdata command with -Xutf8 it has always solved this problem for me:

```
python -Xutf8 manage.py dumpdata app.mymodel > app/fixtures/mymodel.json
```

Here is an article for reference:
https://dev.to/methane/python-use-utf-8-mode-on-windows-212i

Answer (score 3):

After good research, I got the solution.
In my case, `datadump.json` file was having the issue.

- Simply Open the file in notepad format
- Click on save as option
- Go to encoding section below & Click on "UTF-8"
- Save the file.

Now you can try running the command. You are good to go :)

For your reference, I have attached images below.

[Notepad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIrFf.png)

[Save as](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkJV6.png)

[UTF-8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Y798.png)

Answer (score 2):

I found one way to solve this issue by manually re-output a new binary json file with following code, `rb` stand for "read and binary", `wb` for "write and binary".

First, go to shell:

```
python manage.py shell
```

Second, rewrite the test.json to a binary file:

```
with open('path/to/test.json', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
newdata = open('newfile.json', 'wb')
newdata.write(data)
newdata.close()
exit()
```

Then you can load the file:

```
python manage.py loaddata newfile.json
```

Above code works for me. Hope it can help you as well.

Answer (score 2):

i encountered the same problem when loading data. it has a problem with encodings. install notepad ++. and change the encoding format to UTF-8

in the lower right corner you can see the current encoding. if it is not UTF- 8, you can simply change it to UTF-8 form the encoding menu tab.

this solution worked for me.

[orginal post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53643254/unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xff-in-position-0?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using newer versions of windows 10 you can use notepad to change the encoding from UTF-16 to UTF-8 simply by saving the file again and selecting the encoding option on the save dialog. See the example image below.

Comment: Please can you link to the image

Comment: Wondering why the Django manage.py dumpdata saves it in UTF-16 to begin with, anyone knows?