# pisa html to pdf issue with greek stressed letters used with django

Tags: python, html, django, pdf, pisa

I am using pisa to generate a pdf from html in a django application. My view code is the following

```
if request.method == 'POST':        
    return write_to_pdf(request.POST['convert'], { }, 'file')
```

where convert is a TextArea from which i get the value to write on my pdf file

write_to_pdf

```
def fetch_resources(uri, rel):
    path = '%s/media/pdf/' % RHOMBUS_PATH
    return path

def write_to_pdf(template_data, context_dict, filename):
    print template_data
    template = Template(template_data)
    context = Context(context_dict)
    html = template.render(context)
    print html
    result = StringIO.StringIO()
    pdf = pisa.CreatePDF(html.encode('UTF-8'), result, link_callback=fetch_resources, encoding='UTF-8')
    print result.getvalue()

    if not pdf.err:
        response = http.HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s.pdf' % filename
        response.write(result.getvalue())
        return response
    return http.HttpResponse('Problem creating PDF: %s' % cgi.escape(html))
```

The generated pdf though has a problem when the TextArea has greek stressed characters like

```
ά έ
```

etc. I tried changing the encodings but nothing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also had this issue with Greek characters (instead of stressed characters I received black boxes). As a first step you need to change your font to a proper one (like dejavu sans). To do this, add a `style` element to your html template like this:

```
<style type='text/css'>

    @font-face {
        font-family: "DejaVuSansMono";
        src: url("fonts/DejaVuSansMono.ttf");
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: "DejaVuSansMono";
        src: url("fonts/DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf");
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: "DejaVuSansMono";
        src: url("fonts/DejaVuSansMono-Oblique.ttf");
        font-style: italic, oblique;
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: "DejaVuSansMono";
        src: url("fonts/DejaVuSansMono-BoldOblique.ttf");
        font-weight: bold;
        font-style: italic, oblique;
    }

    *, html {
        font-family: "DejaVuSansMono";
    }

    html {
        padding:10pt;
    }

</style>
```

Now, the dejavusans font can be downloaded from http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Main_Page. Also, there are various issues with the location that you will put the font files - I have provided some insight on my answer to [trouble in converting unicode template to pdf using xhtml2pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393607/trouble-in-converting-unicode-template-to-pdf-using-xhtml2pdf/20703217#20703217). As a first step, I propose to put these fonts in `C:/fonts` (or `/tmp/fonts` if using unix) and use the absolute url for `@font-face`, for instance

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "DejaVuSansMono";
    src: url("c:/fonts/DejaVuSansMono.ttf");
}
```

After that, check my answer to see how you can use relative urls.

Finally, I have to mention that I've only tested the above with dejavu-sans (and it works fine) - however I'd really like to know if the above solution works fine with other fonts, like Calibry - if you test it please provide feedback.

If the above doesn't work, please take a look at the `render_to_pdf` function I use:

```
def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    context = Context(context_dict)
    html  = template.render(context)
    result = StringIO.StringIO()

    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(html.encode("UTF-8")), result, path= settings.PROJECT_PATH) 

    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return HttpResponse('<pre>%s</pre>' % escape(html))
```

Comment: should it be in c:\ the fonts?Can't they be in /media/fonts/DejaVuSansmono.ttf e.g?

Comment: Of course, put it wherever you like, just provide an absolute path to the ``src`` of font-face !

Comment: Not working. The pdf renders the page (not all of it but i guess that has to do with the context_dict i am passing). The generated pdf has only what is prepopulated on the template (some <p> some <h4>) and the stressed characters appear to be squares. I saved fonts in /media/fonts and used url('/media/fonts/font.ttf'). The html is generated with dejavusans but not the pdf.

Comment: Check permissions. Also please create the pdf using the ``pisa.pisaDocument`` call I provide in my answer (it is different from yours).

Comment: Î•Î»Î»Î·Î½Î¹ÎºÏOEÏ‚ Î¤Î¯Ï„Î»Î¿Ï‚ this is what i got now for greek words. Permissions? /media/ folder is accessible by django project (used for uploading and serving uploaded files)

Comment: Check that your template.html is in ``utf-8`` ? Also, has the font of the rendered pdf been changed to dejavusans now ?

Comment: yes. The html has changed, in dejavusans and shows utf-8 characters normally. Page encoding is UTF-8(checked chrome settings). I am on windows machine.

Comment: I asked if your template source is in UTF-8 (check it with notepad++)... So is it working now ?

Comment: UTF-8 without BOM is the encoding of html. Unfortunatelly not working. I don't get the same fonts on html and pdf, like dejavu sans are loaded on my html but not on my pdf. :(

Comment: Do you use an absolute path ? What is the *full* path of where you have put your fonts ? Please put them to c:/fonts/ and use the URL I mention in my original answer. I am positive the problem is with the non-absolute path. When you asked me to put them in /media/fonts I thought that you were using Unix and /media/fonts was an absolute path from the root of your filesystem !!!

Comment: No...:(...Placed fonts inside c:\fonts and in  my css i did
@font-face {font-family:"DejaVuSansMono; src:url("c:/fonts/font.ttf");} still nothing. The same squares...Or I should say back to square one...:)...Is "@font-face" for the pdf generator or for the webpage too? It is correct in my code. I copied pasted from yours.

Comment: In our case, the ``@font-face`` is used by the pdf generator - so it is used server-side. So your python code needs to access the font. Also, what you have written to the ``@font-face`` is **not** what I'd written:  ``@font-face {
    font-family: "DejaVuSansMono";
    src: url("c:/fonts/DejaVuSansMono.ttf");
}`` ! what is font.ttf ? and where is src ?

Comment: my template:
<style>
    font-face {
        font-family: "DejaVuSansMono";
        src: url("c:/fonts/DejaVuSansMono.ttf");
    }
 
    font-face {
        font-family: "DejaVuSansMono";
        src: url("c:/fonts/DejaVuSansMono-BoldOblique.ttf");
        font-weight: bold;
        font-style: italic, oblique;
    }

    *, html{
        font-family:"DejaVuSansMono";
    }
</style>
<p>Αυτή είναι μια ελληνική φράση</p>

I used all your font-faces just couldn't right whole template here I used "@" too but won't let me add comment with it

Comment: I give up ! In my case it is working fine, I really can't figure out what is different with your setup. The problem is that pisa cannot find your ttf file. Try putting some ``print``statements inside ``xhtml2pdf/context.py`` to see where does it search for the fonts.

Comment: Thank you for trying :)...Will do that, Good to hear from a fellow greek in here!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43757/discussion-between-apostolos-and-serafeim)