# Unable to get content from JSON file in php

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to get content from a JSON file to put it in MySQL database using PHP, here is how I've been trying so far.

**This is the JSON file `AK.json`:**

```
[
{
    "CompanyName": "Logo Shirts Direct",
    "StreetAddress": "1001 Commerce Parkway South Dr Suite E",
    "Region": "Greenwood",
    "State": "IN",
    "PostCode": "46143",
    "Phone": "(888) 341-5646"
},
{
    "CompanyName": "L.F. GRAPHICS LLC",
    "StreetAddress": "Paterson, ",
    "Region": "Paterson",
    "State": "NJ",
    "PostCode": "07524",
    "Phone": "(973) 240-7033"
},
{
    "CompanyName": "Pacific Sportswear And Emblem Company",
    "StreetAddress": "San Diego, ",
    "Region": "Diego",
    "State": "CA",
    "PostCode": "92120",
    "Phone": "(619) 281-6688"
}
]
```

**and in PHP:**

```
<?php
$filename = 'AK.json';
$content = file_get_contents($filename);
print_r(json_decode($content,true));
?>
```

When I execute this script nothing happens, also I tried the `gettype()` function to get the type of the variable it returns `NUll`.

Comment: when I try to print it without `json_decode` function it prints out the string, and I want to manipulate it in json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your AK.json having a BOM. You can test it with

```
$bom = pack("CCC", 0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf);
if (0 === strncmp($content, $bom, 3)) {
    echo "BOM detected - file is UTF-8\n";
    $str = substr($content, 3);
}
```

[Here is how you get rid of BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295472/how-do-i-remove-the-bom-character-from-my-xml-file) and [What is BOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-different-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom)

---

[Source: PHP Snippet](https://anupamsaha.wordpress.com/2011/08/02/detecting-utf-byte-order-mark-using-php/)

Comment: it returns `string(214) "[ { "CompanyName": "Logo Shirts Direct", "StreetAddress": "1001 Commerce Parkway South Dr Suite E", "Region": "Greenwood", "State": "IN", "PostCode": "46143", "Phone": "(888) 341-5646" } ]"`

Comment: is there any problem with my PHP version or some extension?

Comment: I think you have a BOM in your AK.json.
You can test it with
`$bom = pack("CCC", 0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf);
if (0 === strncmp($content, $bom, 3)) {
    echo "BOM detected - file is UTF-8\n";
    $str = substr($content, 3);
}`

Comment: BOM detected - file is UTF-8, What is this? and how to eliminate this?

Comment: [How to get rid of BOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295472/how-do-i-remove-the-bom-character-from-my-xml-file) and [What is BOM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-different-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom)

Answer (score 0):

can you do :

```
$filename = './AK.json';
$content = file_get_contents($filename);
if($content === false){ 
  echo 'something wrong here';
}else{
  print_r(json_decode($content,true));
}
```

I think the problem is the path to your ressource AK.json, be sure he is in the right place :)

Comment: the given path is just fine, because when I echo the content without `json_decode` function it prints out the string data. but when I apply the `json_decode` it becomes NULL

Comment: so like @Gabscap said it might be a BOM, to remove it go [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290849/how-to-remove-multiple-utf-8-bom-sequences-before-doctype)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
$data='
[
{
    "CompanyName": "Logo Shirts Direct",
    "StreetAddress": "1001 Commerce Parkway South Dr Suite E",
    "Region": "Greenwood",
    "State": "IN",
    "PostCode": "46143",
    "Phone": "(888) 341-5646"
},
{
    "CompanyName": "L.F. GRAPHICS LLC",
    "StreetAddress": "Paterson, ",
    "Region": "Paterson",
    "State": "NJ",
    "PostCode": "07524",
    "Phone": "(973) 240-7033"
},
{
    "CompanyName": "Pacific Sportswear And Emblem Company",
    "StreetAddress": "San Diego, ",
    "Region": "Diego",
    "State": "CA",
    "PostCode": "92120",
    "Phone": "(619) 281-6688"
}
]';
echo '<pre>';
print_r(json_decode($data,true));
echo '</pre>';
```

if its working then your AK.json file is contain any character outside of []

Comment: its working, but I need the content that's not in the same file

Comment: check any space or character included in that file .if you have character included then remove that