# Remove hidden characters from XML

Tags: xml, byte-order-mark

How can I remove these hidden characters that are at the beginning of the file (before `Allitems`)? When I open the file regularly, they can't be seen of course. Used an online tool that detected them.

How can I prevent them from appearing in the first place (using some SaaS that generates XMLs)?

```
XML document: 
1   Ã¯Â»Â¿<Allitems>
2   
3   <Item>
4   <PostTitle>Must Have 1000 Hacking Tut</PostTitle>
5   <UserName>Mr.HacKer</UserName>
6   <ForumName>Advanced Hacking Tutorials</ForumName>
7   <PostLink>http://offensivecommunity.net/showthread.php?tid=676</PostLink>
8   <PostContent>HEllo IHF Guys
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a **[Byte Order Mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)**, an optional 4-byte indicator of the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) (byte order) of the file.  You cannot prevent a BOM from occurring in the first place if you don't control the source of the file, but you can remove it...

### BOM Removal

You can follow the instructions offered by the [W3C for the removal the BOM from HTML pages](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark#remove), which apply to XML as well.  Various other Stack Overflow answers also offer ways to remove a BOM:

- [Using VIM:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/300474/290085)

  ```
  # vim file.xml
  :set nobomb
  :wq
  ```
- [Using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3202807/290085) a standalone Windows freeware program, [File BOM Detector](http://www.bryntsoft.com/filebomdetector.htm).
- [Using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/291462/290085) a freeware Windows editor, [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm): Under the **Format** menu, select **Encode in UTF-8 without BOM**.