# Solr with Carrot2

Tags: solr, carrot2

I'm trying to integrate Solr with Carrot2 clustering engine.I successfully managed to do clustering via Solr following this link : Result Clustering I'm getting the same output as mentioned in the techproducts example.I'm not able to visualize clustering through carrot when I try to give Solr as source there and process it. If I try so I'm getting the following error-

Processing error: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Content is not allowed in prolog.

how to rectify this error??

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something is not quite right with the XML file you are trying to use (not sure which one). Check that it looks correct, maybe run it through XML validator.

One - hidden issue - could also be [Byte Order Mark (BOM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32114841/remove-hidden-characters-from-xml).